# Twilio Media Stream over web sockets is extremely staticky when saving to a file

Tags: websocket, twilio, audio-streaming

I have a python program that initiates a websocket from a Twilio phone call and saves the audio from that phone call to a WAV file in the file system. It works!  My program switches to a websocket, and I am able to buffer the audio to a bytearray and save that array out to a WAV file. All is well, but when I try to play that audio file back, it is very staticky and sounds like it is very low quality. I am not sure if that is the actual quality of the audio stream over the websocket or if I am doing something wrong with receiving or saving the audio.  I am including the program here.

```
# Program to accept a phone call via Twilio and save what the speaker says to a WAVE file
# Need to have ngrok, FastAPI and Twilio all setup properly

import os
import json
import base64
import wave
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, Request, WebSocketDisconnect
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, Response
from jinja2 import Template

app = FastAPI()

# Global variables
wsserver = []

# Set the filename for writing the media stream
output_filename = "output.wav"

# Our buffer where we will queue up all the streamed audio
pcmu_data = bytearray()

# Default values, but will be overriden when we get our "start" message
channels = 1  # Mono
sample_width = 1  # 8-bit samples for PCMU
frame_rate = 8000  # Typical frame rate for PCMU

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    global wsserver
    await websocket.accept()
    wsserver.append(websocket)
    while True:
        message = await websocket.receive_text()
        await on_message(websocket, message)

async def on_message(websocket, message):
    global wsserver
    global frame_rate
    global channels
    global pcmu_data
    global sample_width

    try:
        msg = json.loads(message)
        event = msg.get("event")

        if event == "connected":
            print("A new call has connected.")

        elif event == "start":
            print(f"Starting Media Stream {msg.get('streamSid')}")
            print(msg)

            # Override our default values with what our start message tells us
            channels = msg['start']['mediaFormat']['channels']
            frame_rate = msg['start']['mediaFormat']['sampleRate']

        # The event that carries our audio stream
        elif event == "media":
            payload = msg['media']['payload']
        
            if payload:
                # Decode base64-encoded media data
                media_bytes = base64.b64decode(payload)

                # Add the data onto the end of our byte array
                pcmu_data.extend(media_bytes)

        elif event == "stop":
            print("Call Has Ended")

            # How long was our mulaw stream
            frames = len(pcmu_data)

            # Create a WAV file with an initial number of frames set to 0
            with wave.open(output_filename, 'w') as wav_file:
                wav_file.setnchannels(channels)
                wav_file.setsampwidth(sample_width)
                wav_file.setframerate(frame_rate)
                wav_file.setnframes(frames)
                wav_file.writeframes(pcmu_data)

    except WebSocketDisconnect as e:
        print("WebSocket disconnectedL {e}")
        wsserver.remove(websocket)


@app.post("/")
async def post(request: Request):
    host = request.client.host
    print("Post call - host=" + host)
    xml = Template("""
    <Response>
        <Start>
            <Stream url="wss://83b4-73-70-107-57.ngrok-free.app/ws"/>
        </Start>
        <Say>Please state your message</Say>
        <Pause length="60" />
    </Response>
    """).render(host=host)
    return Response(content=xml, media_type="text/xml")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Listening at Port 8080")
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

This successfully works, but the audio stream that is saved to the file system is extremely staticky.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from using wave to the pywav library. Switched the writing of the code to the following and it came out crystal clear:

```
data_bytes = b"".join(pcmu_data)
wave_write = pywav.WavWrite(output_filename, 1, 8000, 8, 7)  # 1 stands for mono channel, 8000 sample rate, 8 bit, 7 stands for MULAW encoding
wave_write.write(data_bytes)
wave_write.close()
```